# D3.js chord diagram: when uploading, error "can't find variable: d3"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been working on a Chord Diagram using D3.js. When connecting it to a local server (using Brackets live preview) the diagram works just fine. But I now tried to upload it to GitHub and I get the following error and warning messages in the console:

[Warning] [blocked] The page at (my GitHub gh-page) was not allowed to run insecure content from http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js?2.8.1.

[Warning] 
[blocked] The page at (my Github gh-page) was not allowed to run insecure content from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif|PT+Serif:b|PT+Serif:i|PT+Sans|PT+Sans:b.

[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d3
    Global Code (financial-flows:68)

I saw that others faced similar problems and it was suggested to add the local script of d3.js in case it couldn't be accessed for some reason. I did that (at least I think I did: I copied the file, saved it as a .js file in the folder, and added a script line in the index). It sill doesn't work. Any idea what the problem may be? The error message come in the line "var formatPercent = d3.format(".1%");"

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js?2.8.1" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
```

```
var width = 1020,
height = 1020,
outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 4 - 10,
innerRadius = outerRadius - 24;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".1%");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(innerRadius)
.outerRadius(outerRadius);
```

Comment: Try `https`. Just a curiosity, not related to your question: why v2? This is a 2011 version! You know that D3 is on v4, don't you?

Comment: hm.. good question. I used a template and I assume it is a rather old one. good hint though thanks will change it.

Comment: saaay whaaat? It actually worked with the s! Can't believe it. Thanks mate.